# Health Bar in Batch Game

Tags: batch-file, progress-bar

I have a batch game and I need to make a health bar for a character. I have the following variables: `Max_Health`, `Current_Health` and `Health_Percent`.

I would like a way to use the `Health_Percent` variable to create the health bar like this.

If the character has:
`Max_Health` = **500** `Current_Health` = **500** then `Health_Percent`= **100**
So the bar would look like:

Health: 100% =====.=====.=====.=====.=====

And if the character has:
`Max_Health` = **500** `Current_Health` = **250** then `Health_Percent`= **50**
So the bar would look like:

Health: 50% =====.=====.===

Where each `'='` means **4%** of the health and the health bar is separated every 20% with a `'.'`

You can leave out the `'.'` if it makes things too difficult however.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Tony Dude, `250/500` is `50/100`.

Comment: @Monacraft, That's what I get for reading a post while drinking. :P

Comment: Its important to know the OP wants the file to round up in the percentage bar, when CMD normally rounds down. This can be done by seeing if rounding occured through modulous.

Comment: I don't mind mind how cmd rounds, I just want the bar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitted mine to realise Aacini had beaten me to it. However this code is probably a lot better, because it error checks and is more customisable (As well as the fact his includes `.` as part of the bar. Also, for mine you need to calculate the percentage before calling it. This was used a long time ago when I thought batch was appropriate for game dev (A REALLY long time ago).

Here's my code:

### Health.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set test=%~1
set /a health=%~1
set print=%~2

:: Remember to check if errorlevel is 1 after calling script
:: If not check which error occured based of its value.

if "%health%" EQU "" (
Echo Error: No Health Inputed!
Exit /b 2
)
if "%health%" NEQ "%test%" (
Echo Error: Please Input an integer!
Exit /b 3
)
if %health% GTR 100 (
Echo Error: Please Input a number within 0-100!
Exit /b 4 
)
if %health% LSS 0 (
Echo Error: Please Input a number within 0-100!
Exit /b 5
)
if "%print%" EQu "" (
set print=#
)
if exist tmp.e del tmp.e
<nul set /p=%print% 1>nul 2>tmp.e
set /p wrong=<tmp.e
del tmp.e
if "%worng%" NEQ "" set print=#


<nul set /p"=Health: %health%%%  "
set /a repeat=health/20
set /a remain=health%%20
for /l %%a in (1, 1, %repeat%) do (
<nul set /p=%print%%print%%print%%print%%print%
if %%a LSS !repeat! (
<nul set /p=-
)
)
if %remain% EQU 0 Goto :END

<nul set /p=-
set /a repeat=remain/4
set /a round=remain%%4
for /l %%a in (1, 1, %repeat%) do (
<nul set /p=%print%
)

if %round% GTR 0 (
<nul set /p=%print%
)

:END
Echo.
endlocal
exit /b 1
```

To use simply:

```
C:\> Health.bat 43
Health: 43% #####-#####-#

C:\> Health.bat 50 $
Health: 50% $$$$$-$$$$$-$$$

C:\> REM ^B is avhieved by Keystroke of "Ctrl+B"
C:\> Health.bat 67 ^B
Health: 67% ☻☻☻☻☻-☻☻☻☻☻-☻☻☻☻☻-☻☻

C:\> REM Normally if you tried to use an "&" it would cause lots of errors
C:\> Rem However I have speacial code to check for that.
C:\> Health.bat 6 &
Health: 6% ##

C:\> Rem and the best thing is now you can have multichar hp blocks
C:\>Health.bat 26 ^V^U^V
Health: 26%  ▬§▬▬§▬▬§▬▬§▬▬§▬-▬§▬▬§▬
```

And it will do what you want.

The basic parameters are:

```
 Health [Health Percent]
 Health [Health Percent] [HP Block]
```

Note I changed the default health bar to be `#####-#####-##` since it looked a lot better than `-----.--`.

Mona

Comment: This was extremely useful, however, I had to delete `set test=%~1
set /a health=%~1` for it to work because it was claiming that the integers I had put in were not integers at all! :)

Comment: No not really, to test it I inserted `set /p health=43` near the start and ran the batch file. What does the `Health.bat 43` do?

Comment: I also use `Û` instead of `#` because it gives a square, shaded box which makes the bar look more realistic.

Comment: @Carl479 If you save this as `Health.bat`, and then open `cmd`, use `cd` to come to the directory containg health.bat, and lastly type `Health.bat 43` It would run the batch file as a program and print a health bar for forty-three. If you put your game in the same directory, anytime you want to print out a health bar simply `Health.bat %health%` and it will print the bar out. That's what both Aacini and I thought you were doing.

Comment: @Carl479 Look at my edit. I've used some of my newer knowledge of batch to make this code so flashy I've considered restarting one of my old batch projects!

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you could call batches like that, I usually use the `CALL` command.

Comment: What does the
`%~1` & `%~2` do? Are they the parameters?

Comment: Hmm, works perfectly when done with cmd, but when when I tried `pause
Health.bat 32 #
pause` in a batch, the bar flashed on then the batch quit...

Comment: @Carl479 Make sure the pause is on the line after, other wise there should be no problems. Also, you can use `Health.bat 12 WORD` And it will return `Health: 12% WORDWORDWORD` which is also prety kool.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem For this example, take Max_Health and Current_Health from parameters
set /A Max_Health=%1, Current_Health=%2

set "bar======.=====.=====.=====.====="
set /A Health_Percent=Current_Health*100/Max_Health, barLen=Health_Percent*29/100

echo Max_Health=%Max_Health%, Current_Health=%Current_Health%, Health_Percent=%Health_Percent%
echo/
echo Health: %Health_Percent%%% !bar:~0,%barLen%!
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test 500 500
Max_Health=500, Current_Health=500, Health_Percent=100

Health: 100% =====.=====.=====.=====.=====

C:\> test 500 250
Max_Health=500, Current_Health=250, Health_Percent=50

Health: 50% =====.=====.==
```

Comment: The dot spacer between each multiple of 20 makes the spacing non-linear. I don't think there is a simple multiplier that can be used to get the correct answer. Your formula gives `=====.` for 24%, when it should give `=====.=`. A corrected formula is `barLen=Health_Percent/25+Health_Percent/20-1`.